# Why can ''rm *(1)*'' delete files which do not contain the string "(1)" in their names?

Tags: bash

I used the rm command in my downloads folder (windows subsystem for linux). although I told it to delete anything with (1) within it, all the files in the downloads folder were removed. Why would this have occurred?

```
rm *(1)*
```

Comment: Let me guess, you have the `extglob` option enabled? (It's off-by-default, but it's not unheard of for distro defaults to turn it on in their dotfiles).

Comment: See output of `echo rm *(1)*`.

Comment: @Cyrus, ...*grumble* re: suggesting `echo` for debugging; as an alternative, `set -x; : rm *(1)*; set +x` is going to be more closely representative (using quotes or backslashes to distinguish between syntactic and literal whitespace, showing hidden characters, &c); likewise, `printf '%q ' rm *(1)*; echo` does a comparably good job at showing a true representation even when filenames contain unusual characters.

Comment: @Cyrus, ...(as you well know), `echo rm *(1)` doesn't show the difference between that expanding to `rm 'Hello World(1)'` and `rm Hello World(1)`, but they're very different things.

Comment: See "File Name Generation" in the `ksh` man page, or extglob under the "Pattern Matching" section of the `bash` man page.

Comment: BTW, as a note for the future, questions about command-line usage rather than script development are typically a better fit for our sister site [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

`*(...)` is [extglob syntax](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) for "zero or more of `...`".

Thus, you told your shell to pass `rm` an argument list consisting of all file which start with zero or more `1`s, and then have any suffix following. Every possible filename matches this pattern, so the result is equivalent to `rm *`.

---

If you want to be certain that a substring is literal rather than treated as glob syntax, always quote it:

```
rm -- *'(1)'*
```

...is going to behave consistently on all POSIX-superset systems, including ones that implement `extglob`-like extensions.